# Use Stripe funds to make a payment

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm implementing the payments using Stripe in an e-commerce website. I'm searching for the functionality to make a payment using the funds from the balance (a feature that is available in Paypal). Is Stripe supporting this method of payment?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported, generally speaking, and your customers generally will not be aware they are interacting with Stripe unless you're using one of the hosted products like Checkout.

A version of this is possible if you manage your own [customer balances](https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/customer/balance), which can be applied against invoices & subscriptions.